# Is there any way to add additional serial type of id column while importing .csv file?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a record table in postgresql.

```
Create table record:
(
recordid serial not null,
name varchar,
handedness varchar,
height numeric,
weight numeric,
average numeric,
hr numeric,
constraint pk_record primary key (recordid)
);
```

I fired one import command:

```
postgres=# copy record from 'C:\postgesql_demo_csv\baseball_data.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;
```

I got one issue.

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "Tom Brown"
CONTEXT:  COPY record, line 2, column recordid: "Tom Brown"

**Can anyone help me .....?**

Answer (score 2):

Either include *all* columns when you export the data, or if not then specify which columns of the table to copy the data into:

```
COPY record (name, handedness, height, weight, average, hr) from ....
```